# Unexpected behavior of the unix echo command

Tags: shell, unix

while writing some script i found the following issue ,

suppose

```
set x = "param[xyz]";
echo $x
```

the output was echo:No match

But when i do ,

```
echo "$x"
```

i got the output: param[xyz]

so echo is doing a two way substitution ,
Initially **echo $x** was converted to **echo param[xyz]** and then it tried to look for the param[xyz] value .

But Ideally it should have just printed the variable whatever provided to it .
Does this behavior is a valid use case?

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does no substitution at all, it's the shell that does it. It depends on the shell you use, but it seems that you are using a shell of the family of c-shells. Shell expands variables in the command line, so the first step is to generate:

```
[csh] echo param[xyz]
```

and then the shell does file match expansion, but as there is no file that correspond to the pattern the shell answers that there is no match. The message is somehow misleading as the shell reminds you what "command" was concerned not that the command failed by itself.

In the second try, enclosing the variable inside `"` prevent the shell to do other expansion and the shell launch the command with the argument obtained after the first expansion.

There exists another prevention if you use `'`, the shell won't ever expand variables:

```
[csh] echo '$x'
$x
```

Please refer to shell documentation and especially about expansion.

Another experience to convince you is to try with an non existing command:

```
[csh] weirdo z*
weirdo: No match
```

which is different than an non existing command:

```
[csh] weirdo
weirdo: Command not found.
```

If you'd use other shell behavior would be different:

```
[bash] echo z*
z*
```

because that shell produces as the argument the string itself in the case file matching is not working.

With:

```
[zsh] echo z*
zsh: no matches found: z*
```

the behavior is much more similar to c-shells but the message is much more clear, the shell failed at matching.

Comment: Thank you , got the concept :)